# Could not establish trust relationship for the ssl/tls secure channel with authority '10.137.4.121:8086 wcf service svcutil in project .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, api, wcf, .net-core, service

> Could not establish trust relationship for the ssl/tls secure channel with authority '10.137.4.121:8086 wcf service svcutil in  project net core 3.1

My file `Reference.cs`:

```
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
{
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.Service_MDMSSoap))
        {
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true;
            result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

            return result;
        }

        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.Service_MDMSSoap12))
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            textBindingElement.MessageVersion = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.CreateVersion(System.ServiceModel.EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressingVersion.None);
            result.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            httpsBindingElement.AllowCookies = true;
            httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            httpsBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);
            return result;
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
}
```

When I call service, I get the alert shown above.

```
Service_MDMSSoapClient sv1 = new Service_MDMSSoapClient(0);
            
ArrayOfXElement a = sv1.GET_READ_IX(tungay, denngay, username, pass);
```

Please help me resolve this problem

Comment: TLS is performed before an HTTP Request is sent to establish and encryption key.  TLS uses a certificate that must be loaded in both client and server for TLS to work.  The error indicates the connection did not complete which can be for many reasons.  The error is due to a timeout so it could mean that a route doesn't exist between the client and server of TLS failed.  You are using Core 3.1 which is old and the encryption mode of the certificate may not work.  Also older machines may (cell phones) may not implement the encryption mode.  You are also using port 8086 which is not standard.

Comment: It is best to use a newer version of Core which may solve issue.  Make sure the certificate is loaded in the stores on both client and server.  Validate there is a route between client and server using PING.  And make sure the service is running on the server at port 8086.  You also may need to turn proxy off if you are using a proxy.  Proxy could contain errors.

Comment: You can help me handle without changing the version net core

Comment: Does a ````System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (a,b,c,d) => true;```` line solve the problem? If yes then something with certificate trust relation is not okay. You can stick with this line if you do not care or establish the trust.

Comment: I try it not work

Comment: I need more info.  Getting working with Core 3.1 may not be possible with certain encryption modes.  Has code every worked?  If so, what has changed?  I need to know what type of machines are the client and server.  Need the encryption mode in the certificate.  Best way of debugging is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check the TLS blocks.  See what version of TLS is being used (should be either TLS 1.2 or 1.3).  Then look at the TLS Certificate block that is sent from server to client which has list of certificate names.  This info should help determine where to look next.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add some certification like this:

```
BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://myserver/MyService.svc"));
factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, endpointAddress);
factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication();
factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

Comment: I try it not work